# How to get selected row's title and value in uipickerview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uipickerview

in my iphone project i need to get data from sqlite and show it on uipickerview then with selected row's value i need to fill another uipickerview

in my table T_REGION there is two columns ID and NAME

this is how i get REGION list

```
- (NSArray*) getRegions
{

const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select ID,NAME from T_REGION"];
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,
                           query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {



            NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                              (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            [resultArray addObject:name];


        }
        sqlite3_reset(statement);

        return resultArray;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"problem");
    }
}
return nil;
}
```

as you see i cant fill ID column to array only name column returns i need ID column to fill another uipickerview (you may think as country - city relationship)
this is my first problem

now this is how i fill my pickerview

first in viewDidLoad method i get array:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
[self getdata];
}

- (void)getdata {
 dataRegion = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: [[DBHelper getSharedInstance:@"2_program.db"]getRegions]];


}
```

and my uipickerview delegate methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
if (pickerView.tag == 1)
    return [dataRegion count];
else
    return 0; //[countryTypes count];

}


- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
if (pickerView.tag == 1)
    return [dataRegion objectAtIndex:row];
else
    return @"";


}


 - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:  (NSInteger)component
 {
if (pickerView.tag == 1) {
    NSString *categoryType  = [dataRegion objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    [btnBolge setTitle:categoryType forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}else {



}

  }
```

what i want is what select option tag do in html.  i need 2 columns but show only 1 and get the selected row's value not text

1- how can i return 2 columns in getRegions function?
2- how can i show only name column in uipickerview and get its selected row's id column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This..     May be help full..

Like this you can add both array as dictionary

```
 NSMutableArray *nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Come",@"Say",@"Go", nil];
    NSMutableArray *regionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Hi",@"Hello",@"Bye", nil];


    NSMutableArray *mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int index = 0; index<regionArray.count; index++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dataAddDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dataAddDic setValue:[nameArray objectAtIndex:index] forKeyPath:@"name"];
        [dataAddDic setValue:[regionArray objectAtIndex:index] forKeyPath:@"region"];
        [mainArray addObject:dataAddDic];
    }
    NSLog(@"Data Print %@",mainArray);
```

After you need to change you delegate functions

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
if (pickerView.tag == 1)
    return [mainArray count];
else
    return 0; //[countryTypes count];

}


- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
if (pickerView.tag == 1)
    return  [[mainArray objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"region"];
else
    return @"";


}

 - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:  (NSInteger)component
 {
if (pickerView.tag == 1) {
    NSString *categoryType  = [[mainArray objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:@"name"];
    [btnBolge setTitle:categoryType forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}else {

 }

 }
```

Comment: but there is no array for id column as you see. i need one more array or something to fill id column i have only names of regions first i need to get ids then someway i need to get selected uipickerview row's index

Comment: I think you are trying to get data from Two array. Right or wrong.

Comment: yes right. but if i create another array i cant return it because my method returns only one array i dont want to connect to sqlite 2 times so maybe dictionary solves my problem but i dont know how to fill dictionary with 2 arrays

Comment: I have updated my answer like as example but you need to replace data on both array 1. "nameArray" , 2. "regionArray". try this .. May be help full .. thanks ..

Comment: Have checked or not ... If It's helping you than accept my answer .. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];  
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)  
{  
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select ID,NAME from T_REGION"];  
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];  
    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];  
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)  
    {  
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)  
        {  
            NSString *id = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8Strin  
                (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];  

            NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:  
                (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];  

            NSDictionary *dict = @{id:name};  
            [resultArray addObject:dict];  

        }  
        sqlite3_reset(statement);  

        return resultArray;  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            NSLog(@"problem");  
        }  
    }  
    return nil;  

}  
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row  forComponent:(NSInteger)component  
{  

    if (pickerView.tag == 1){  
        NSDictionary *region = [dataRegion objectAtIndex:row];  
        NSArray *keys = [region allKeys];  
        return region[[keys[0]];  
    }  
    else{  
        return @"";  
    }  

}  

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:   (NSInteger)component  
{  
    if (pickerView.tag == 1) {  
        NSDictionary *region  = [dataRegion objectAtIndex:row];  
        NSArray *keys = [region allKeys];  
        [btnBolge setTitle:region[keys[0]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
    }else {  

    }  
}
```